# DataMapper: Putting a model into a model

Tags: sinatra, datamapper

In the [DataMapper documentation for associations](http://datamapper.org/docs/associations) I found an example where they put a model into a model like...

```
 1 class Person
 2 
 3   class Link
 4 
 5     include DataMapper::Resource
 6 
 7     storage_names[:default] = 'people_links'
 8 
 9     # the person who is following someone
10     belongs_to :follower, 'Person', :key => true
11 
12     # the person who is followed by someone
13     belongs_to :followed, 'Person', :key => true
14 
15   end
16 
17   include DataMapper::Resource
18 
19   property :id,   Serial
20   property :name, String, :required => true
21   ...
```

Does it have any influence on the result you get back or is it just another notation or format?

Thanks in advance, rufus

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't have any influence on the result.

If you put your models in a namespace it will reflect in storage names though. That's why in the example above you see "storage_names[:default] = 'people_links'" in Link model, because that model is inside Person namespace, which is reflected in "people_links" table name.